# Cannot see file created from WSL on Bitlocker drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bitlocker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've got an NTFS external drive with Bitlocker enabled on it. If I create any file on it from WSL, for example using `touch /mnt/e/testing.txt`, I can see that file from WSL using for example `ls /mnt/e`.

However, if open the drive from Explorer, the drive just appears empty (with just a hidden "System Volume Information"). My understanding was that it's not possible to access WSL-only files from Windows (those in "lxss" directory) but any file created from WSL on an outside drive should be visible, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Any idea what might be the issue? Is it due to Bitlocker? Or do I need to format my drive in a special way?

Comment: Try to use latest Windows 10 version. There are some issue related to bitlocker https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/search?q=bitlocker&type=Issues.

Comment: Also "not possible to access...".. not true.  You can very much access the WSL files under ' / '.  Read them all day long but modify them at your own peril.  Anything mapped under '/mnt/' should be fair game (just as you assume).